# Which OLS Regression Results are worth putting into an article? Does my example look right?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels, least-squares

My research area consists of a river and two rows of wells, one closer to and one further away from the river, in a north-south direction.

[image]

In my research problem, I want to show using statistics that the river I am studying significantly affects the water quality of the row of wells closer to it (a process called bank filtration is at work). At the same time, the second row of wells is also influenced to some extent by the river, but not as much as the first row. To do this, I decided to collate laboratory physicochemical data (e.g. chlorides or sulphates in [mg/L]) from the river and the two well rows and compare them statistically.

I rearranged the data regarding the sampling location (river, row A and row B).

Below, I insert an example output for one group of parameters (chloride content in water):

I used method: `cl_spring_reg = smf.ols('cl ~ location', data=cl_spring).fit()` and then `cl_spring_reg.summary()` and got:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:               chloride   R-squared:                       0.487
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.480
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     65.04
Date:                Thu, 24 Aug 2023   Prob (F-statistic):           1.38e-20
Time:                        21:40:43   Log-Likelihood:                -372.99
No. Observations:                 140   AIC:                             752.0
Df Residuals:                     137   BIC:                             760.8
Df Model:                           2                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=====================================================================================
                        coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept            14.6316      0.806     18.162      0.000      13.038      16.225
location[T.row A]    -0.2420      0.900     -0.269      0.788      -2.021       1.537
location[T.row B]     7.0957      0.964      7.361      0.000       5.189       9.002
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       41.716   Durbin-Watson:                   1.416
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              121.766
Skew:                           1.122   Prob(JB):                     3.62e-27
Kurtosis:                       6.979   Cond. No.                         5.84
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Do I correctly understand that in a nutshell:

- The R-square is 0.487, which means that the model explains about 48.7% of the variability in the data.
- The F-statistic is 65.04, and the associated p-value is a very low 1.38e-20, suggesting that at least one of the model coefficients is significant.
- Since p for T.b was small (<0.05) and for T.a was high, it means that between the river and row A closer to it, there are no significant differences in means and between the river and row B, there are.
- Parameter estimates (coef) imply that there is a small difference between row A and the river (the Intercept in this case?) and between row B and the river the difference is higher.

Did I get it right? Also, which other results from this output are worth noting? Also, keep in mind that if I keep the OLS in the paper, I would need to do the same for 17 other groups of parameters, so I need to be concise with the number of results in the Table.

I also don't get why, since I have 3 location groups, there are two "location" outputs, namely "location[T.a]" and "location[T.b]"? Is, let's call it "location[T.river]" an "Intercept" in this output?